# Unfirom convexity of the Sobolev space in the subelliptic case

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded open set and $X=(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_k)$ be a smooth vector field satisfying the Hormanders finite rank (of rank $N$) condition. Suppose $1<p<\infty$ and let $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is the Sobolev space defined as the closure of $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ under the norm
$$
\|u\|=\|Xu\|_{L^p(\Omega)},
$$
where $Xu=(X_1 u,X_2 u,\ldots,X_k u)$ is the gradient of $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$. Can someone please inform if the space $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is a uniform convex space? It is known that $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is a separable and reflexive Banach space, but unable to find results concerning the uniform convexity. Any reference would also be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the precise definition of $X_i u$? I guess that it is not pointwise multiplication?

Comment: $X_i$ is a vector field acting on $u$.

Comment: This was already written in your question... Sorry, then I cannot help you.

Comment: You can consider any Hormander smooth vector field as mentioned. It is a general vector field. Even for Heisenberg group are you aware of uniform convexity? Thanks.

Comment: @Mathguide: You're in a very specific situation; in this case, it might be best to write down all relevant definitions (like what you mean by a Hormander finite rank condition. That way you can reach people that may be familiar with Sobolev spaces, but maybe not the vector field constructions).